# angularjs resource Authentication Header based on request body

Tags: angularjs, header, hmac

I'm trying to use Resource with APIs protected by HMAC authentication methods. So I need to append "Authentication" header to the request.

In this example code I get the Article from the API with GET and update it with "update" custom method. For the update I need Authentication header. The problem is that `$scope.article` is `undefined` when I define the header.

`getAuth` function calculates the sign.

Suggestions?

```
function EditCtrl($scope,$resource,articleId) {
    var Article = $resource('/blog/articles/:articleId',
    {articleId:articleId}, {
        update: {
            method:'PUT',
            headers: {Authentication: getAuth('key','PUT','/blog/articles/'+articleId,$scope.article)}
        }
    });

    var article = Article.get();
    $scope.article = article;

    $scope.save = function(){
        article.$update();
    }
}

function getAuth(key,verb,resource,data) {
    //data is undefined there

    content_md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(JSON.stringify(data));
    message = verb+'\n'+resource+'\n'+content_md5;
    hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(message, key);

    var sign = "AuthHMAC 0123456789:"+hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    return sign;
}
```

Comment: for setting up dynamic auth you have to use request interceptor to set authentication dynamically

Comment: I have found only http response interceptor

Comment: let me try to set up a plunker for you

Comment: the plunker may not offer you the greatest of solution but this is a very good workaround http://plnkr.co/edit/Iwk6gTdqYZAvXgRWROIc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I improve Alan's solution using three elements:

- factory service that shares the key
- controller that sends the httpRequest
- httpRequestInterceptor that sets the header

The controller calls a setKey()  provided by a factory service that calculates the header. Finally the httpResponseInterceptor sets the header of request calling getKey() provided by a factory service.

Solved!

Comment: You would have some directions on defining and using such an interceptor ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar right now.

I believe the answer lies in using $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest functions, I don't have it complete yet, but the basics as described in the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

I think are this:

```
var authModule = angular.module('my.AuthModule', [], myAuthModuleCfg);

function myAuthModuleCfg($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(myRequestSigner)
}

function myRequestSigner(data, headersGetter) {
    // do some signing, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies for only posting a link instead of an entire solution) have a look at ['Monofraps's **angular-node-hmac-example**](https://github.com/Monofraps/angular-node-hmac-example) on GitHub (MIT license).

For Hmac/SHA512 encryption, it uses the (deprecated) [CryptoJS library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), which I'd probably swap for the [Forge cryptographic library](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) ([CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) has now been abandoned).

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried it, but if you look at lower level API `$http`, it has a methods that take in config as a parameter. This config i think contains the `headers` property that you can update before making the request. Here is the signature for PUT

`$http.put(url, data, config)`